# How to know whether given is variable of specific class?

Tags: c#

I want to know whether passed object is actually reference of variable of specific class or not.

Consider below structure of some class 'ClassA':

```
public classA
{
string variable1;
int variable2;

method1(ref variable1);
}
```

Now if in class that contains implementation of method1(Obj object1), I want to check that 'object1' is which variable of specific 'ClassA' ?

Because I want to check in if condition like if object1 is variable1 of ClassA then //to proceed with logic....

Please provide a small example for the same.

Comment: your code does not compile

Comment: Please say why you want to do this. And say why you believe you need `ref`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: first fix your syntax and then learn what can be asked
.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to overload the method rather than play around with refs and ifs. But it's very hard to tell what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you could get to this in safe code is using expressions, but honestly you probably **don't want to do this**. It'd be a nightmare to try and debug, and there's probably another way to go about it. For example, is there any reason variable1 can't be of a specific type?

Now that I've spoken reason, the approach using expressions goes something like this (This is from a debugging helper, I would never use this approach in anything remotely serious. Note: A lot of exception handling and other code is stripped from this, also note how ugly and hackish it looks, that's all why you really shouldn't do this):

```
public static void DoStuffWithParameter<T>(Expression<Func<T>> paramExpression)
{
        if (paramExpression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("paramExpression");

        var body = ((MemberExpression)paramExpression.Body);
        var paramName = body.Member.Name;
        var param = ((FieldInfo)body.Member)
             .GetValue(((ConstantExpression)body.Expression).Value);
        var declaringType = param.DeclaringType;
        var paramValue =  paramExpression
    .Compile()
    .Invoke();
        if(declaringType.Equals(typeof(ClassA)))
        {
            //do stuff 
        }
}
```

To use that you'd use something like:

`DoStuffWithParameter(()=>myClass.VarA);`

Comment: Note this will crash and burn if the function passed isn't a member, all reasons you **really shouldn't do this**.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. The simplest way to do this is to pass object of sender in method1 and proceed, like below.

```
method1(Object sender, ref Object var)
{
if(sender is classA)
 {
    classA senderObj= (classA) sender;

    if((string)var == senderObj.variable1)
    {
       // Logic for variable1
    }
    else if((int)var == senderObj.variable2)
    {
       // Logic for variable2
    }
   . . .
 }
}
```

Comment: Very bad code. And why does `var` need to be `ref`? Do you ever set it in the method?